# Wireguard Docker and Verizon optic router

Tags: networking, network-share, wireguard

This is likely a very trivial issue answered multiple times but my knowledge is not enough to recognize/implement.

Problem:

- I can connect to my self-hosted wireguard server and access admin panel from outside. I can also use the VPN to access services within my home network. I however don't have access to the internet when I am connected via VPN. This worked before and something went wrong after reboot or software update (?).
  Details:
- I need Wireguard for external-external access (e.g access US interet from abroad)
- Wireguard is self-hosted on Synology NAS with vanilla configs like here
- Internet is via Verizon Fiber. Port forwarding is enabled for UDP 51820 → 51820, UDP 51821 → 51821. As I mentioned, I do have handshake access and access to intranet via this VPN
- Router `G3100` Firmware `3.1.1.18`

Client config is also pretty vanilla:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <redacted>
Address = 10.8.0.3/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = <redacted>
PresharedKey = <redacted>
AllowedIPs = ::/0, 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <redacted>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 0
```

What do I miss?